# Set Android screen timeout settings programmatically?

Tags: android, timeout, screen

The old way pre-KitKat was to use the following:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY); 

android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

This no longer works as of API 19 or above.

Comment: what do you mean, It no longer works?

Comment: The intent gets sent, but the timeout settings never get updated, and whether you set it at 5 minutes or 5 seconds, the timeout value always remains unchanged.

Comment: @Kyle you are Right I check it..